# Unit testing in angular using IIFE throw a reference error?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, iife

I am currently working on writing a simple test case for the driver script using IIFE(Immediately invoked function expression). Here is my driver script.

driver.js

```
(function() {
"use strict";

var app = angular
    .module("myApp", [
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "ui.sortable"
    ]);
}());
```

Here is my spec driver.spec.js

```
describe("application configuration tool driver", function() {
 it("should create an angular module named myTest", function() {
    expect(app).toEqual(angular.module("myApp"));
 });
});
```

When I run my spec using IIFE. I am getting a ReferenceError: app is not defined.

If I run the driver script without IIFE:

```
var app = angular
    .module("myApp", [
        "ui.bootstrap",
        "ui.sortable"
    ]);
```

My spec passes. Any thoughts on passing the spec using IIFE?

Comment: variable `app` is local to IIFE, but the test `expect(app).toEqual(angular.module("myApp"));` makes no sense to me.

Comment: why do you even need variable `app`?

Comment: I was using the variable `app` for creating custom directives and controllers.

Comment: @charlietfl some poorly written examples of how to use angular show `var app` in combination with `app.controller ...`, `app.factory ...` and unfortunately people aren't aware this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Claies I was reading about it recently but my intention in here was that all my controllers, directives are wrapped up in IIFE. So for a brief demo I used the variable app.

Comment: @Teja to the point I was making in the other comment, it's better to use the module getter `angular.module("myApp").controller ...` than to attach the module to a variable.  As long as you don't use the setter (`angular.module("myApp",[...])...`) more than once, you don't need `var app`.  The getter will always return the same instance of your module.

Comment: further to my point, I just answered a question that illustrates what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246645/angular-filter-not-working/33246764#33246764

Comment: @Claies I got your point. I have been following the style guide by johnpapa(https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) where he uses the `angular,module("myApp") ...` way.

Comment: right, so using that style, then app isn't necessary, so this is no longer a question that needs an answer?

Comment: @Claies I was wondering on how to test the variables whose scope is inside the IIFE?

Comment: as was mentioned in the provided answer, you really can't, unless you can expose the variable outside the IIFE.  if you *could* test internally scoped variables, you would sort of be invalidating the purpose of IIFE in the first place.

Comment: @Claies Oh got you. Thanks for clarifying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move `app` back to the outer scope (if that's an option you can take, of course):

```
var app;
(function(app) {
    "use strict";

    app = angular
        .module("myApp", [
            "ui.bootstrap",
            "ui.sortable"
        ]);
}(app));
```