# Angular filter not working

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, filter, angular-ngmodel

I am coding a filter that will format phone numbers in a contact form I've built however for some reason the value in the input is never being updated and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <input name='phone' ng-model='home.contact.phone' placeholder='(Area code) Phone' required ng-bind='home.contact.phone | phone' />
</div>
```

and here's my filter:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'

    angular
        .module('Allay.phoneFilter', [])
        .filter('phone', function () {
            return function (phone) {
                if(!phone) return '';

                var res = phone + '::' // Since this isn't working, I'm doing something super simple, adding a double colon to the end of the phone number.
                return res;
            }
        });
})();
```

I'm not sure if you need this, but here's the controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'

    angular
        .module('Allay', [
            'Allay.phoneFilter'
        ])
        .controller('HomeController', function () {
            var home = this;
        });
})();
```

If I add an alert(res) before 'return res' in the filter I see the value I expect '123::', however the value in the input it's self is still just 123.

Comment: Where would I do that? I haven't seen anything in the docs about needing $scope.$apply() with a filter.

Comment: Ok, since you just changed the content of the question to invalidate my answer, I will leave this with the assumption that one of the other answers will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need create directive to change your ngModel, like this:

```
.directive('phoneFormat', function() {
     return {
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

             var setvalue = function() {
                 elem.val(ctrl.$modelValue + "::");
             };

             ctrl.$parsers.push(function(v) {
                 return v.replace(/::/, '');
             })


             ctrl.$render = function() {
                 setvalue();
             }

             elem.bind('change', function() {
                 setvalue();
             })

         }
     };
 });
```

Use in html:

```
<input name='phone' ng-model='contact.phone' placeholder='(Area code) Phone' required phone-format />
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57czd36L/1/

Comment: It's not necessary to create a directive, his approach using filters was right.

Comment: @Cyberdelphos here is your solution http://jsfiddle.net/wuxfurdn/ and in console is error -  Non-assignable model expression: contact.phone | phone (<input name="phone" ng-model="contact.phone | phone" placeholder="(Area code) Phone" required="">)

Comment: I thought the idea was to use directives to modify the DOM behavior or add behavior to the controller and to use a filter when transforming a value such as I am doing.

Comment: I tried this however it doesn't appear to watch the home.contact.phone for changes as the :: is only added to the initialized value and isn't added when you edit the value.

Comment: Since it is an input, then a directive is needed, you are right Bartosz

Comment: The filter module is great for expressions, say {{phone | phoneFilter}} but when it comes to input fields it gets messy .. :) a directive can be helpful

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it will work as you want and it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Although a filter module is a good approach, I use an `'A'` directive to do the dirty work because changing the element value will affect its ng-model.

**However**, I would only suggest this kind of solution if your actual data manipulation could sum in 3-4 lines of code; otherwise, a more thorough approach is needed.
This is an example that will delete anything which isn't an integer:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    angular.module('Allay').directive('phoneValidator', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                angular.element(element).on('keyup', function() {
                    element.val(element.val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/, ''));
                });
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

And than in your HTML template :

```
<input name="phone" ng-model="home.contact.phone" placeholder="(Area code) Phone" phoneValidator required/>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `ngBind` on the input is not quite correct. From the documentation,

> The `ngBind` attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes

You do not need to replace the text content of the `<input>` element, that wouldn't make sense. You can instead extend the formatter pipeline of the `NgModelController` using a directive like

```
app.directive('phoneFormat', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                if (value)
                    return value + '::';
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in your HTML,

```
<input ng-model='home.contact.phone' phone-format />
```

In case you wanted to keep the filter you wrote (for other usages), you can actually re-use it in the directive like

```
app.directive('phoneFormat', [ '$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$formatters.push($filter('phone'));
        }
    }
}]);
```

`$filter('phone')` simply returns the filter function registered under `'phone'`. Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qvbQnDLqvnZdt7miDjVI?p=preview).

---

Note, this solution will only format data when you change the `$modelValue` of the `NgModelController`, for example like

```
$scope.$apply('home.contact.phone = "123-456-7890"');
```

If you are looking for something to update/format the value of the input *as the user is typing*, this is a more complicated task. I recommend using something like [angular-ui/ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask).

Comment: @xRoyDot, Agree with you, that is a correct direction to go. But "masking" an input value as the user is typing is a notoriously difficult task to do _well_. When done improperly, it is very very annoying to the user. For example, you have to worry about preserving cursor position when editing the middle of the input. ui-mask _does_ do the task well.

Answer (score -2):

You should remove your "ng-bind" cause you are filtering it and what is presented is what in the ng-model. use value instead.

```
    <input name='phone' ng-model='home.contact.phone | phone' value="{{contact.phone | phone}}"  />
```

see working example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0ekLwsr/4/)

Comment: He has already changed/corrected the double module definition in his question... so only your first point applies here...

Comment: For some reason the input in your example can't be changed. It's fixed to whatever value it's init with.

Comment: I see that it works using $scope which is odd, but regardless angular best practice says not to use $scope in this way, hence the var home = this; (best practice)

Comment: @efarley - updated my Fiddle. now its not using $scope.